What is weak transitivity?
I recently received referee reports on a paper I submitted. In such paper, I define a binary relation that satisfies the usual requirements of so-called “weak preference relations” in economic theory: namely, a binary relation $R$ on an arbitrary set $X$ is a weak preference relation if and only if it satisfies

Transitivity: for all $a,b,c\in X$, $aRb$ and $bRc$ imply $aRc$,
Completeness: for all $a,b\in X$, $aRb$ or $bRa$,
Reflexivity: for all $a\in X$, $aRa$ (which is implied by completeness).

One reviewer is saying that the preference relation I define should be weakly transitive (rather than transitive). Unfortunately, I have never heard of weak transitivity before, and I can’t find it anywhere in the authoritative sources I generally use. Therefore, I cannot evaluate the referee’s comment.
My question is two-fold:

What is weak transitivity?
Is it normal to define a weak preference relation with axioms other than transitivity, completeness and reflexivity?

In my paper, I am saying that a preference relation $R$ satisfying transitivity, completeness and reflexivity is a weak ordering. Thus,

Should I call it total pre-order instead?


As you tag Economics, I would guess you are talking about quasi-transitivity, as that comes up in Choice Theory.  If your relation is anti-symmetric, then this is the same as transitivity but anti-symmetry is not assumed.

Thank you very much for your comment. Since I am not assuming anti-symmetry, it is my understanding that transitivity implies quasi-transitivity. Am I correct?

Yes. $\quad$ $\quad$
